# Element mask on gradient background keeping it responsive

Tags: css

I have an element with a gradient in the background. I have to put a label above it, with which it shares the gradient: by resizing the screen, the label will slide over the element below but the gradient must remain consistent.

In this image you can see the starting structure:

[image]

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, rgb(162, 30, 30) 0%, rgb(27, 57, 172) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.element-1,
.element-2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.label {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element-1">
    <div class="label">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result that I would like to obtain:

[image]

This is how it should be with a narrow width screen:

[image]

What I need is a "mask effect": I tried the properties css clip, clip-path, mask-image, but I couldn't do what I need.

The only solution I found was to add pseudo-elements with white background before and after to cover everything except the label, but the final layout will be much more complicated than this example and it seems like a rather dirty solution to me (there are border-radius and I had to add small pseudo-elements to cover the corners as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.element-2 {
  height: 100px;
  clip-path:inset(0);
}

.label {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20%;
  clip-path:inset(0);
}

.label:before,
.element-2:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  inset:0;
  background: linear-gradient(100deg, rgb(162, 30, 30) 0%, rgb(27, 57, 172) 100%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="label"> label here </div>
  <div class="element-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! I've tried many ways, but this is one solution I hadn't thought of. I only changed inset to polygon, because I needed rounded edges on the top of the label (like border-radius).

Comment: @VinzClortho if you want rounded edge, change clip-path with mask: `-webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff 0 0)` and then you can use border-radius